# Putting keyword data into a csv file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

Given a table of the following format in MATLAB:

```
     userid | itemid | keywords
A = [ 3        10       'book'
      3        10       'briefcase'
      3        10       'boat'
      12       20       'windows'
      12       20       'picture'
      12       35       'love'
      4        10        'day'
      12       10        'working day'
      ...     ...        ... ];
```

where `A` is a table of size (58000*3), I want to write the data in a csv file with the following format:

**csv.file**

```
    itemid  keywords
      10    book, briefcase, boat, day, working day, ...
      20    windows, picture, ...
      35    love, ...
```

where we the list of `itemids` is stored in `Iids = [10,20,35,...]`

I would like to avoide using loops for this as you can imagine the matrix is big-sized. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to think of a solution without loops. But you can optimize your loop by:

- using logical indexing
- running such loop only *M* times (if *M* is the number of unique `itemid` elements) instead of *N* times (if *N* is the number of elements in your table).

The solution I come up with is this.
First of all, create your table

```
A=table([3;3;3;12;12;12;4;12], [10;10;10;20;20;35;10;10],{'book','briefcase','boat','windows','picture','love','day','working day'}','VariableNames',{'userid','itemid','keywords'});
```

which looks like

[image]

Select the unique values for column `itemid` (your `Iids`):

```
Iids=unique(A.itemid);
```

which looks like

[image]

Create a new, empty, table which will contain the results:

```
NewTable=table();
```

And now the minimal loop I've come up with:

```
for id=Iids'
    % select rows with given itemid value
    RowsWithGivenId=A(A.itemid==id,:);

    % create new row in NewTable with the id and the (joined together) keywords from the selected rows
    NewTable=[NewTable; table(id,{strjoin(RowsWithGivenId.keywords,', ')})];
end
```

Also, append the new column names in `NewTable`

```
NewTable.Properties.VariableNames = {'itemid','keywords'};
```

And now NewTable looks like:

[image]

*Please note*: due to the fact that the keywords in the new table are separated by comma, a csv file is not the format I recommend. By using `writetable()` as `writetable(NewTable,'myfile.csv');`
what you'll get is

[image]

As instead, by replacing `;` instead of a separating comma (in `strjoin()`), you'll get a nicer format:

[image]